# Mklink to a password protected folder

Tags: mklink

I have machine **A** and a `C$` share on machine **B**.

On machine B, I only have access to the share and nothing else (it is password protected). How can I `mklink` from machine A to the `C$` share invoking username and password for `C$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all issue a standard NET USE command specifying the user name and password to the remote machine & share that you want to map to.

Then, issue

```
mklink /d \\<remote machine\<remote share <folder where you want to map the share>
```