# mklink to a remote shared folder, with remote account

Tags: windows, network-shares, symbolic-link, authentication, shared-folders

#### Difference to qustion [Creating a symbolic link to mapped network drive in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/210824/creating-a-symbolic-link-to-mapped-network-drive-in-windows)

1. Referenced question is about building symlink to a **mapped network drive**. This question doesn't say anything about network drive, but a **shared folder**.
2. Answers in referenced question are all about how to use `mklink` correctly, and how to get privileges for `mklink`. in this question **`mklink` is used correctly**, and the link file is successfully created.

#### Original question

I have a workstation `10.255.255.200` with a shared folder `10.255.255.200\Share\Data`. To access `Share` folder from remote I need to enter username/password of a local account.

I want to make a symlink on another computer, put at `C:\User\UUU\AppData\Roaming\UData`, directing `10.255.255.200\Share\Data`.

I use this command `mklink /D C:\User\UUU\AppData\Raoming\UData \\10.255.255.200\Share\Data` to create a symlink, but when I enter the created link using File Explorer it says *username or password is invalid*.

I can login to `10.255.255.200\Share` from File Explorer, and check the folder content. I followed [Mklink to a password protected folder](https://superuser.com/questions/488470/mklink-to-a-password-protected-folder) and tried `net use S: 10.255.255.200\Share\Data * /user:uuuu /persistent:yes` and executed successfully, but nothing change when I click on the created symlink. The symlink is also unable to recognize path containing `S:`.

So hwo can I make the symlink work correctly? Or there's something I got it wrong?

Comment: You should put your explanation of why this is not a duplicate ***into the question itself***.  Nobody is going to see your edit summary comment. Also, please don’t put the answer *in* the question.